# GCE instance hangs after some time

Tags: linux, google-compute-engine

**Image:**
Debian GNU/Linux 7.6 (wheezy) amd64 with backports kernel and SSH packages built on 2014-10-17

**Machine type:**
n1-highcpu-2 (2 vCPU, 1.8 GB memory)

**Zone:**
urope-west1-b

I have 10-20 ruby workers which listen for external RabbitMQ server. Nothing special minimizing css/js/html code, upload pictures via http, transfer data from MongoDB to Mysql.

Everything works fine, but after some time (several hours ~5-6) instance hangs. I can't ssh to it from external client or browser console.  Only instance reboot helps.

What should I check? or change? or whatever to fix this behavior?

Comment: I would check your serial port output. You can see this by going to your instance in the Developers Console and clicking on "View Output" at the bottom of the page. If that does not allow you figure out the problem, I suggest you include that output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons of "hanging" might be IO throttling. You'd need to understand disk access patterns and see if your disk type/size is a good match.

Please refer to this section of documentation that explains Compute Engine disk performance:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdperformance